# Connect to wifi using custom iPhone/Android app without SSH

Tags: wifi, connection, android, ios

I'm new to this and would like to ask a question.
Is it possible to connect raspberry pi zero w to wifi like this:

https://youtu.be/9yTg-iWPy28?t=84
or
https://youtu.be/2l3NBCWbjwk?t=15

I want to create my own doorbell with a camera and maybe give it to someone else and also want to make it easy for them to connect using an app without doing it in SSH.
I have some knowledge in iOS development in swift but have no idea how is stuff like this done.

In the video it does not seem that they are connecting using bluetooth.

In the second video as if I understand correctly, the app is generating QR code that holds ssid and psk and by scaning the QR code camera tries to connect to wifi using that ssid and psk right?

Can you hint me where should I start or what should I look for?
Or maybe how would you do such connection?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, but as it stands there not a focused question here.  A Pi and a smartphone can communicate using protocols for hardware they both possess -- primarily bluetooth  and IP (TCP/UDP etc) networking over wifi.  If you have specific questions about that, that's great (although general network programming questions are more appropriate to our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)).  Asking for information on "everything except SSH" is way, way too broad a net.

Comment: Please read *["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* and note the paragraph that includes, "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much".  Everything but SSH is not just one book but a whole series.

Comment: You need to decide for yourself whether you want to use bluetooth or wifi or something else (image/QR code recognition, etc).  If you need to research things about that you will, again, have to be (much, much) more specific when asking questions here.  Please understand **this is not a discussion forum**, and open-ended invitations to brainstorm or dialogue back and forth don't work with the format.   Please also take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: Taking that part related to Raspberry-Pi the answer to this question: `Is it possible to connect raspberry pi zero w to wifi like this:` , the answer is : `YES`

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? Currently trying to do the same thing and not sure where to start